# "du" ou "de" correction d'un texte

Tags: grammaire

Je viens de rédiger un texte en français mais je ne sais pas laquelle de ces deux expressions et juste :

**du partage de savoir**

ou

**du partage du savoir**

Voici le texte tout entier.

> "Travailler et évoluer dans un environnement en plein prospérité,
>   mettre mes compétences au service des élèves les guident dans les
>   ténèbres, sculpter les cerveaux et savourer le plaisir du partage de
>   savoir et de la réussite de l'autrui."

Il se peut qu'il existe d'autres fautes ; indiquez-les, s'il vous plaît.

Merci par avance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il s'agit du *partage **du** savoir*.

Voici quelques commentaires sur le texte :

*...plein prospérité...* : faute d'accord et peu idiomatique.

*...les guident dans les ténèbres* : le sujet de *guide* est *mettre* donc *guider* doit être au singulier. D'autre part, *guider dans les ténèbres* est trop pompeux.

*Sculpter les cerveaux* est j'imagine une traduction littérale de *mind sculpture*. Elle ne passe pas vraiment en français.

Contrairement à *autre* (*la réussite de l'autre*), *autrui* ne prend jamais d'article donc :
*...et de la réussite **d'autrui***.